# add more time with google/token, being able to fetch cal events at any time during a day?

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-api, token, google-oauth

Sorry for the long question but I simply wonder: how do I add more time to be able to for example run my app during the whole day and be able to fetch calendar events through google API using oauth2 authorization...

I'm having issue in my project and get an error invalid_request in the terminal and I'm pretty sure it is because it kind of, does not let me try to get events after a certain of time.. which I think is around 1h approximately. I'm building my project with react, nodejs, express, using google API.

If you need more content let me please know! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Access Tokens expire after 3600 seconds (default). You will need to refresh the access token periodically. You can do this without prompting the user if you requested offline access.

You can decode an access token. One of the fields is the expiration time (exp), so that you can determine when to refresh. See the second link below. You do not actually need to call a Google endpoint as you can decode the access token in code. If I remember correctly it is a base64 encoded JWT.

I am not sure what API you are using as there are several, but this link will point you in a direction on how to refresh access tokens.

[Refreshing an access token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices#offline)

[Calling the tokeninfo endpoint](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#calling-the-tokeninfo-endpoint)

Comment: sounds good.. I'm using googles API calendar, do you have any tutorials on how to refresh this properly? is it hard

Comment: Refreshing an access token just means issuing a new one. Keep track of when you issued the token and before it expires get a new one.